Basic questions regarding a computer
I'm an Undergraduate CS student.  My understanding of a "computer" is that it is simply a machine that can "carry out" a set of instructions. The set of instructions it can ever understand is the set of machine code that the computer was built to understand.
I read that at the early stages in the development of computers, the early computers was very basic. It was simply a machine which was connected to a "terminal", i.e., mono-colored screen which has a prompt that allows us to write a machine code (or assembly language instructions such as MOVE \$2, \$4 etc). The computer would then carry out that instruction and we would be prompted to type in our next command.
I was wondering, with the computers that we purchase today, how can we access such "program" or "software", i.e., mono-colored screen which allows us to write/execute the machine code?

Hi @D.W. thanks for your advice, I've edited it now. I've provided two related questions under one post because I'm a newbie and they limit me to post 2 separately posted questions. I hope you understand.

We don't allow asking multiple questions in a single post.  Rate-limiting may force you to wait a little bit before asking your third question.. so please wait to post your third question, and don't evade the rate-limiting by putting multiple questions in one post.

Hi @D.W. thanks for your comment. It's OK.

There was never a time when you could connect a screen terminal directly to a CPU. Direct human interaction with a computer is by reading and writing bytes by flipping switches (up=0 down=1 or vice versa) to select the address in binary and the data value in binary, then pressing the "write" button. And this was used in computers for a long time. Even after there was more advanced software, humans would have to enter the first stage bootloader with the switches.
A computer is too stupid to control a screen without software to control it, and if you add that software, you're not "directly" controlling the computer since there is something in the way that is controlling the screen, and keyboard. This is called a machine code monitor program, and it was popular on early home computers. They're like crude versions of today's debuggers.
Now we have advanced so far that your computer doesn't come with a switch panel. But that doesn't mean you can't get down to the direct CPU level. You can still write a program in assembly, or machine code, and you can use a debugger to run your program one instruction at a time. Obviously the CPU isn't just running one instruction of your program at a time, since it's refreshing the screen, and checking the internet for updates, and putting the pixels in the terminal window - your program is just a slice of what the computer is doing, but your program thinks it has the computer all to itself (mostly) and that means you can still program the same way as before if you want to (mostly).

A terminal is neither necessary nor sufficient for writing machine code.  The best way to write machine code today is to learn to write assembly code, and try writing some programs in assembly code.  (This has little or nothing to do with terminals; how the assembly code is entered is unimportant, and whether it is entered on a color or black-and-white screen is unimportant.)
If you become proficient in assembly language, you can then try to write programs directly in machine code if you want, though there likely is little value to that.  Learn to walk before running, and learn to jog before sprinting.  I suggest you learn to write assembly code before trying to write machine code in binary directly.

Hi D.W., thanks for your comment. This hasn't quite fully answered my question, I was wondering, "where" can I be writing that assembly language to execute it on a computer? I understand that I am unable to ask two questions in a single post, but it's difficult to avoid. Where can I even find the assembly language for the computer ?

It's OK to not answer the latter question.
But what I'm asking is "where/how (which software) can I execute that assembly language" ?

@user1514263, There are many classes that teach assembly language programming (many universities have classes where materials are freely available on the web), and many tutorials on the web.  Basically, you write a file containing assembly code, then run an assembler to generate an executable file, and run the executable.  I suggest doing some searching and I suspect you'll find some resources.

Ah... I think I'm starting to understand. Thank you very much for your comment.

A system long before terminals: N switches that let you set a binary address. M switches that let you set a binary value. A “store” button that stores the value at the address. A “run” button that starts the running code at address 0. And some lights that display the contents of a speicific memory cell.
